# could not save the list changes to the server” in designer

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, custom-form

I am trying to create custom new/edit forms in a SharePoint online site
but it shows this error:

Could not save the list changes to the server

I have tried these solutions:

- Deleted website cache related to designer.
- checked list settings. there are no lookup columns or calculated clumns included.
- Uninstalled designer and installed SharePoint Online components.
- There are no special characters in site name or list name.
- Also checked permissions. I have full control permissions on the site and am a Global Admin
- Manually set all all sites in site collection to DenyAddAndCustomizePages $false
- Custom scripts are enabled in the admin centre

The only other cause of this error I can find is an enabled site feature with the GUID "e374875e-06b6-11e0-b0fa-57f5dfd72085" but finding and disabling features by their GUID's isn't possible with SharePoint online.

What else can I do?

Answer (score -1):

The solution “disable e374875e-06b6-11e0-b0fa-57f5dfd72085 feature” is for SharePoint on-premise not for SharePoint online.

To troubleshoot the issue, check things below:

1. Check if there are the lookup column and the calculated column in the current list. 
   And check if the lookup column and calculated column are correct in the current list.
2. Turn on the “Allow users to run custom script on personal sites” in SharePoint admin center.

Go to Office 365 admin center->SharePoint admin center->settings->custom script->Turn on ”Allow users to run custom script on personal sites” and “Allow users to run custom script on self-service created sites”.

More reference:

SharePoint Designer – Error: Could not save the list changes to the server.

https://drewmadelung.com/sharepoint-designer-error-could-not-save-the-list-changes-to-the-server/

There is a similar post:

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/b71c9a68-84a6-4472-8cbb-b88b77d65160/sp-designer-2013-error-could-not-save-the-list-changes-to-the-server?forum=onlineservicessharepoint